# Patron de rayas en amcharts 5

Tags: javascript, amcharts

tengo este código es un diagrama de gantt que estoy haciendo con amcharts5. Si os fijais en la linea  `fill: horarios2.habilitado_ab === 1 ? "rgba(102, 204, 102, 0.70)" : "rgba(159, 159, 159, 0.32)",` tengo que si está habilitada una cosa salga en verde y si no en gris. Vale pues estoy intentado que esta tenga un patrón de rayas por encima como el **LinePattern** de amcharts 5 pero no lo consigo.

```
              horarios_tabla0.forEach(function (horario, index) {
                var fromHour = new Date();
                fromHour.setHours(Math.floor(horario.min_ini / 60));
                fromHour.setMinutes(horario.min_ini % 60);
            
                var toHour = new Date();
                toHour.setHours(Math.floor(horario.min_fin / 60));
                toHour.setMinutes(horario.min_fin % 60);
            
                var item = {
                    category: "Domingo",
                    fromDate: fromHour.toLocaleTimeString([], {
                        hour: "2-digit",
                        minute: "2-digit",
                    }),
                    toDate: toHour.toLocaleTimeString([], {
                        hour: "2-digit",
                        minute: "2-digit",
                    }),
                    num_prog: horario.num_prog,
                    columnSettings: {
                        fill: horario.habilitado === 1 ? "#02aaf2" : "rgba(159, 159, 159, 0.32)",
                    },
                };
            
                data.push(item);

                if (data_false.is_abonado) {

                var horarios2 = data_false.horarios2[index];
                var fromHour2 = new Date();
                fromHour2.setHours(Math.floor(horarios2.min_ini_ab / 60));
                fromHour2.setMinutes(horarios2.min_ini_ab % 60);
            
                var toHour2 = new Date();
                toHour2.setHours(Math.floor(horarios2.min_fin_ab / 60));
                toHour2.setMinutes(horarios2.min_fin_ab % 60);
            
                    var item1 = {
                        category: "Domingo",
                        fromDate: fromHour2.toLocaleTimeString([], {
                            hour: "2-digit",
                            minute: "2-digit",
                        }),
                        toDate: toHour2.toLocaleTimeString([], {
                            hour: "2-digit",
                            minute: "2-digit",
                        }),
                        num_prog: horarios2.num_prog,
                        columnSettings: {
                            fill: horarios2.habilitado_ab === 1 ? "rgba(102, 204, 102, 0.70)" : "rgba(159, 159, 159, 0.32)",
                        },
                    };
                    data1.push(item1);

                }
            });
            
            if (data_false.is_abonado) {
             data = data.concat(data1);
            }
```

Lo que intenté fue:

```
    // Crear un array de objetos para almacenar los datos del diagrama de Gantt
var data = [];
var data1 = [];

horarios_tabla0.forEach(function (horario, index) {
  var fromHour = new Date();
  fromHour.setHours(Math.floor(horario.min_ini / 60));
  fromHour.setMinutes(horario.min_ini % 60);

  var toHour = new Date();
  toHour.setHours(Math.floor(horario.min_fin / 60));
  toHour.setMinutes(horario.min_fin % 60);

  var item = {
    category: "Domingo",
    fromDate: fromHour.toLocaleTimeString([], {
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
    }),
    toDate: toHour.toLocaleTimeString([], {
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
    }),
    num_prog: horario.num_prog,
    columnSettings: {
      fill: horario.habilitado === 1 ? "#02aaf2" : "rgba(159, 159, 159, 0.32)",
    },
  };

  data.push(item);

  if (data_false.is_abonado) {
    var horarios2 = data_false.horarios2[index];
    var fromHour2 = new Date();
    fromHour2.setHours(Math.floor(horarios2.min_ini_ab / 60));
    fromHour2.setMinutes(horarios2.min_ini_ab % 60);

    var toHour2 = new Date();
    toHour2.setHours(Math.floor(horarios2.min_fin_ab / 60));
    toHour2.setMinutes(horarios2.min_fin_ab % 60);

    var linePattern = horarios2.habilitado_ab === 1
      ? { width: 4, height: 4, pattern: [{ x: 0, y: 0, width: 4, height: 4, path: "M 0 0 L 4 4 M 0 4 L 4 0", stroke: "#000000", strokeWidth: 1 }] }
      : undefined;

    var item1 = {
      category: "Domingo",
      fromDate: fromHour2.toLocaleTimeString([], {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
      }),
      toDate: toHour2.toLocaleTimeString([], {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
      }),
      num_prog: horarios2.num_prog,
      columnSettings: {
        fill: horarios2.habilitado_ab === 1 ? "rgba(102, 204, 102, 0.70)" : "rgba(159, 159, 159, 0.32)",
        stroke: linePattern,
      },
    };
    data1.push(item1);
  }
});

if (data_false.is_abonado) {
  data = data.concat(data1);
}
```

El trocito que está en verde es el que quiero ponerle el patrón:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El patrón viene siendo este mas o menos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la parte donde tienes el relleno de la barra `fill`, lo tienes que cambiar por un patrón de relleno `fillPattern` de la siguiente manera:

```
columnSettings: {
    fillPattern:(horarios2.habilitado_ab === 1)? 
       (am5.LinePattern.new(root, {
           color: am5.color(0xd6e681),
           rotation: 90,
           width: 200,
           height: 200,
           gap: 10
      }):(am5.LinePattern.new(root, {
           color: am5.color(0xd6e681),
           rotation: 45,
           width: 200,
           height: 200,
           gap: 10
      })
    )
  }
```

y creo que la parte de stroke ya no va. Te dejo un link de la [documentación de amCharts donde vienen los fillPattern](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/colors-gradients-and-patterns/patterns/)

Comment: Yo ofrecí los puntos de recompensa, y los mismos se asignarán en el momento oportuno.

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar un patrón de rayas a la línea en lugar de un color sólido, puedes utilizar la propiedad fillPattern en lugar de fill en el objeto columnSettings. El patrón de rayas se define mediante la clase LinePattern, que puedes importar de AmCharts 5.

Prueba con este codigo:

```
// Importar la clase LinePattern
import { LinePattern } from "@amcharts/amcharts5/patterns";

horarios_tabla0.forEach(function (horario, index) {
  var fromHour = new Date();
  fromHour.setHours(Math.floor(horario.min_ini / 60));
  fromHour.setMinutes(horario.min_ini % 60);

  var toHour = new Date();
  toHour.setHours(Math.floor(horario.min_fin / 60));
  toHour.setMinutes(horario.min_fin % 60);

  var item = {
    category: "Domingo",
    fromDate: fromHour.toLocaleTimeString([], {
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
    }),
    toDate: toHour.toLocaleTimeString([], {
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
    }),
    num_prog: horario.num_prog,
    columnSettings: {
      fill: horario.habilitado === 1 ? "#02aaf2" : "rgba(159, 159, 159, 0.32)",
      fillPattern: horario.habilitado === 1 ? new LinePattern({ frequency: 4 }) : undefined,
    },
  };

  data.push(item);

  if (data_false.is_abonado) {
    var horarios2 = data_false.horarios2[index];
    var fromHour2 = new Date();
    fromHour2.setHours(Math.floor(horarios2.min_ini_ab / 60));
    fromHour2.setMinutes(horarios2.min_ini_ab % 60);

    var toHour2 = new Date();
    toHour2.setHours(Math.floor(horarios2.min_fin_ab / 60));
    toHour2.setMinutes(horarios2.min_fin_ab % 60);

    var item1 = {
      category: "Domingo",
      fromDate: fromHour2.toLocaleTimeString([], {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
      }),
      toDate: toHour2.toLocaleTimeString([], {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
      }),
      num_prog: horarios2.num_prog,
      columnSettings: {
        fill: horarios2.habilitado_ab === 1 ? "rgba(102, 204, 102, 0.70)" : "rgba(159, 159, 159, 0.32)",
        fillPattern: horarios2.habilitado_ab === 1 ? new LinePattern({ frequency: 4 }) : undefined,
      },
    };
    data1.push(item1);
  }
});

if (data_false.is_abonado) {
  data = data.concat(data1);
}
```

En este código, se utiliza la clase LinePattern para definir un patrón de rayas con una frecuencia de 4 en caso de que la condición horario.habilitado === 1 sea verdadera. Si la condición es falsa, se asigna undefined a la propiedad fillPattern, lo que hará que la línea tenga un relleno sólido en gris.

Asegúrate de importar la clase LinePattern correctamente y de tener la configuración adecuada para la biblioteca

Answer (score 0):

```js
var linePattern = horarios2.habilitado_ab === 1 ?
    {
        width: 4,
        height: 4,
        pattern: [{
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 4,
            height: 4,
            path: "M 0 0 L 4 4 M 0 4 L 4 0",
            stroke: "#000000",
            strokeWidth: 1
        }]
    } :
    undefined;

var item1 = {
    category: "Domingo",
    fromDate: fromHour2.toLocaleTimeString([], {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
    }),
    toDate: toHour2.toLocaleTimeString([], {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
    }),
    num_prog: horarios2.num_prog,
    columnSettings: {
        fill: horarios2.habilitado_ab === 1 ? "rgba(102, 204, 102, 0.70)" : "rgba(159, 159, 159, 0.32)",
        stroke: linePattern,
    },
};
data1.push(item1);
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.